# Why doesnt the ng-show obey the field.$invalid condition

Tags: angularjs

I need a form to show an error when it is dirty and is invalid according to a regex pattern how ever this does not seem to work. even though the invalid class is there when checked from inspect element

```
<form name="billingAddress">
  <input type="text" ng-model="billingAddress.firstName" name="firstName" ng-pattern="nameRgx" required/>
  <label ng-show="billingAddress.firstName.$invalid && billingAddress.firstName.$dirty">Invalid</label>
</form>
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Z3TNE9kcQYaDPgqzCyr?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

please check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8BvsedGtrhYvRD6w6HIk?p=preview) i fixed your problem.

you need different form name like,

```
 <form name="billingAddressx">

<label ng-show="billingAddressx.firstName.$invalid || billingAddressx.firstName.$error.required">Invalid</label>
```

here `billingAddressx.firstName.$invalid` check invalid state of the input by considering 
 form name = `billingAddressx`
 input name = `firstName`